# Spree as multilingual/bilingual site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, spree

Is spree suitable for multi/bilingual e-commerce site?

By default it supports internationalization (i18n - http://guides.spreecommerce.com/i18n.html). It gives an impression that spree is bilingual friendly but I'm missing one piece of the puzzle. Translation of product names, descriptions, attributes, categories.

What is your good practice when it comes to translation of products and categories (including metadata)?

gem version: Spree 1.1.1

Comment: We've tested https://github.com/jipiboily/spree_multi_lingual - unfortunately it's outdated.

Comment: https://github.com/kamilc/spree-change-locale is a nice utility but it only helps with changing the locale.

Comment: It's 2016. Spree has been discontinued. Hopefully Solidus will fill this gap.

Answer (score 9):

I work on Spree as the Community Manager.

We are actually having [a discussion](https://github.com/spree/spree/issues/1378) at the moment regarding the translation of things within Spree using I18n. Most things are translated, but there's still a few spiky edges that you may come across. We're looking to make that easier for people.

Now in regards to the attributes on products, that's possible using a plugin built by one of the guys in the community, Tomasz Stachewicz, and is called [spree_globalize](https://github.com/tomash/spree_globalize). Give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I'll certainly test it. So far we've had bad luck with products/taxons translations due to outdated plugins.

Comment: The spree_globalize extension says 'WARNING: Intensive merge and re-work in progress. Do not use for now!'

Comment: @MatthijsP thanks. Seems like we are still looking for a working solution :(

Comment: @ryan-bigg We've failed with spree_globalize :(

Answer (score 7):

For our bilingual spree store http://www.artdesanimaux.com we use [spree_multi_lingual](https://github.com/jipiboily/spree_multi_lingual) with Spree 1.1.2 and it is working properly. Don't know why you say its outdated?

We made a few fixes & added translations for shipping methods on [our fork](https://github.com/hooktstudios/spree_multi_lingual)

Comment: Can you please tell in detail how you achieved this or please provide link to the github repository so that I can understand the actual flow.as I am new to Spree and struggling for three days to make it multilingual.